# 401 Unauthorized on every Request made to REST API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I get a 401 unauthorized no matter what ever the request I try. I am even unable to get into `@PostMapping("/signup")` and print to the console. Spring doesn't show any errors. I only get `401 unauthorized` when I try `POST` to signup with PostMan. Here, I am posting the code for WebSecurityConfig and REST Controller to signup with my REST API.

To access the whole code, please visit [https://github.com/BhargaviNadendla/Discussion-Forum--Spring-Boot-Angular](https://github.com/BhargaviNadendla/Discussion-Forum--Spring-Boot-Angular/tree/master/forum-for-all)

WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().formLogin().disable();

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

RestController:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthRestAPIs {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userRepository;

    @Autowired
    RoleDAO roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Autowired
    JwtProvider jwtProvider;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginForm loginRequest) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getAuthorities()));
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpForm signUpRequest) {
        System.out.println("In rest----------------------------------");
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(signUpRequest.getUsername())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Fail -> Username is already taken!"),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if (userRepository.existsByEmail(signUpRequest.getEmail())) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("Fail -> Email is already in use!"),
                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        // Creating user's account
        User user = new User(signUpRequest.getName(), signUpRequest.getUsername(), signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));

        Set<String> strRoles = signUpRequest.getRole();
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

        strRoles.forEach(role -> {
            switch (role) {
            case "admin":
                Role adminRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_ADMIN)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
                roles.add(adminRole);

                break;
            default:
                Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Fail! -> Cause: User Role not find."));
                roles.add(userRole);
            }
        });

        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("User registered successfully!"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

AuthTokenFilter.java

```
package com.springboot.forumforall.jwtauth.security.jwt;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.springboot.forumforall.jwtauth.security.services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;


public class JwtAuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {

            String jwt = getJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && tokenProvider.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = tokenProvider.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Can NOT set user authentication -> Message: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String getJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.replace("Bearer ", "");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @dur added JwtAuthTokenFilter. I suppose the error due to the basic authentication set by spring-security. When i check `localhost:8080` on browser, I get the basic auth form. How to disable this inorder call my API in Postman?

I tried disabling it from `application.properties` but of no use

Comment: Your Spring Boot application class is not in the root directory, so it can't find components like Spring Security's configuration. You have to put it in the root package or to add a component scan.

Comment: Thank you for the catch @dur

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http...
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
           ..
}
```

Which sould be:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http...
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
           ..
}
```

Comment: You can't add antMatchers after anyRequest. You get compile-time exception.